# date format convertion

Tags: asp.net

i have date like

```
string date = calarc.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

where calarc is calender control.

It returns a date in 03-14-2009 format but i want it in 03/14/2009 format.

so how do i do above?

Comment: Are you sure!? Probably this line returns correctly but something else is wrong. How do you check the result?

Comment: yes i am sure. and may be the problem is as Sergej Andrejev said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your current culture is messing with format. Try

```
DateTime.Parse("2009-03-14").ToString(@"MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

As it seems "/" is realy a syntax for separator (similar to M, d, y or any other). That's why it is being replaced with separator specified in culture. This is noted in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator(VS.71).aspx) too.

> If the custom pattern includes the
>   format pattern "/", DateTime.ToString
>   displays the value of DateSeparator in
>   place of the "/" in the format
>   pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The / character in the format specifier doesn't do what you think. It's not a literal character that is copied to the string, instead it's a specifier for the date separator, which in the current culture is the - character.

To use literal characters in the format just put apostrophes around them:

```
string date = calarc.SelectedDate.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested line of code -

```
string.Format("mm-dd-yyyy", calarc.SelectedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",calarc.SelectedDate);
```